# cherry-picking commit - is commit a snapshot or patch?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I have a question related to cherry-picking commits and conflicts.

The 'Pro Git' book [explains](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) that commits are kind of snapshots and not patches/diffs.

But cherry-picking commit may behave as it was a patch.

---

Example below, in short:

1. create 3 commits, each time edit first (and single) line of the file
2. reset the branch to first commit
3. test1 : try to cherry-pick third commit (conflict)
4. test 2: try to cherry-pick second commit (OK)

---

```
mkdir gitlearn
cd gitlearn

touch file
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/gitlearn/.git/

git add file

#fill file by single 'A'
echo A > file && cat file
A

git commit file -m A
[master (root-commit) 9d5dd4d] A
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file

#fill file by single 'B'
echo B > file && cat file
B

git commit file -m B
[master 28ad28f] B
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

#fill file by single 'C'
echo C > file && cat file
C

git commit file -m C
[master c90c5c8] C
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

git log --oneline
c90c5c8 C
28ad28f B
9d5dd4d A
```

test 1

```
#reset the branch to 9d5dd4d ('A' version)
git reset --hard HEAD~2
HEAD is now at 9d5dd4d A

git log --oneline
9d5dd4d A

#cherry-pick 'C' version over 'A'
git cherry-pick c90c5c8
error: could not apply c90c5c8... C
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

#the conflict:
cat file
<<<<<<< HEAD
A
=======
C
>>>>>>> c90c5c8... C
```

test 2

```
#same for 'B' - succeeds
git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 9d5dd4d A

git cherry-pick 28ad28f
[master eb27a49] B
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Please explain why test 1 failed  (I could imagine the answer if commits were patches, but snapshots?)

Comment: There was a merge conflict in the first test. Since you did a reset in the second, it was successful.

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, thanks for the answer, but: 
1) not sure why you broke formatting of the original post 
2) there was hard reset before both tests

Comment: Stack Overflow can be a bit sensitive in when it detects code blocks. @Mr.Polywhirl didn't actually try to change anything other than making it a numbered list, as you can see in the revision history, by clicking side-by-side markdown. Although it would have been possible to spot the formatting problems in the edit preview, I know from experience how easy it is to overlook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Pro Git book is correct: a commit is a snapshot.

You are also correct, though: `git cherry-pick` applies a patch.  (Well, sort of: see further details below.)

How can this be?  The answer is that when you cherry-pick a commit, you also specify which *parent* commit to consider, with the `-m parent-number` argument.  The cherry-pick command then generates a diff against that parent, so that the resulting diff can be applied now.

Should you choose to cherry-pick a non-merge commit, there is only one parent, so you don't actually pass `-m` and the command uses the (single) parent to generate the diff.  But the commit itself is still a snapshot, and it's the `cherry-pick` command that finds the diff of `commit^1` (the first and only parent) vs *`commit`* and applies that.

## Optional reading: It's not *just* a patch

Technically, `git cherry-pick` does a full-blown three-way merge, using Git's *merge machinery*.  To understand why there's a distinction here, and what it is, we have to get a bit into the weeds of diffs, patches, and merges.

A *diff* between two files—or two snapshots of many files—produces a sort of recipe.  Following the instructions won't bake you a cake (there is no flour, eggs, butter, and so on).  Instead, it will take the "before" or "left hand side" file, or set of files, and produce as its result the "after" or "right hand side" file, or set of files.  The instructions, then, include steps like "add a line after line 30" or "remove three lines at line 45".

The precise set of instructions generated by some diff algorithm depends on that algorithm.  Git's simplest diffs use only two: *delete some existing line(s)* and *add some new line(s) after some given starting point*.  That's not quite sufficient for *new* files and *deleted* files, so we can add *delete file F1* and *create all-new-file F2*.  Or, in some cases, we might replace a delete-file-F1-create-F2-instead with *rename F1 to F2*, optionally with additional changes.  Git's most complicated diffs use all of these.<sup>1</sup>

This gives us a simple set of definitions that applies not only to Git, but also to many other systems.  In fact, before Git there were [`diff`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) and [`patch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html).  See also [the wikipedia article on `patch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)).  A very brief summary definition of the two goes like this, though:

- diff: a comparison of two or more files.
- patch: a diff that is machine-readable and suitable for machine-applying.

These are useful *outside* version control systems, and is why they predated Git (though not, technically, version control, which dates back to the 1950s for computing, and probably thousands of years when generalized: I'll bet there were multiple different sketches for, say, the Lighthouse at Alexandria, or the Pyramid of Djoser).  But we can have issues with a patch.  Suppose someone has Version 1 of some program, and makes a patch for a problem with it.  Later, we discover the same problem in Version 5.  The patch may well not *apply* at this point, because the code has moved around—possibly even to different files, but certainly within the file.  The *context* may have changed as well.

Larry Wall's `patch` program handled this using what it called offsetting and [*fuzz*](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Inexact.html).  See [Why does this patch applied with a fuzz of 1, and fail with fuzz of 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6215787/1256452)  (This is very different from ["fuzzing" in modern software testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing).)  But in a true version control system, we can do better—sometimes a great deal better.  This is where the *three way merge* comes in.

Suppose we have some software, with multiple versions in the repository *R*.  Each version *V<sub>i</sub>* consists of some set of files.  Doing a diff from *V<sub>i</sub>* to *V<sub>j</sub>* produces a (machine-readable, i.e., patch) recipe for turning version *i* into version *j*.  This works regardless of the relative directions of *i* and *j*, i.e., we can go "back in time" to an *older* version when *j ≺ i* (the funky curly less-than is a *precedes* symbol, which allows for Git-style hash IDs as well as simple numeric versions like SVN's).

Now suppose that we have our patch *p* made by comparing *V<sub>i</sub>* vs *V<sub>j</sub>*.  We'd like to *apply* patch *p* to some third version, *V<sub>k</sub>*.  What we need to know is this:

- For each patch's change (and assuming that changes are "line oriented", as they are here):

  - What *file name* in *V<sub>k</sub>* corresponds to the file-pair in *V<sub>i</sub>* vs *V<sub>j</sub>* for this change?  That is, perhaps we're fixing some function `f()`, but in versions *i* and *j* function `f()` is in file `file1.ext` and in version *k* it's in file `file2.ext`.
  - What *lines* in *V<sub>k</sub>* correspond to the changed lines?  That is, even if `f()` didn't switch *files*, maybe it's been moved up or down a lot by a large deletion or insertion *above* `f()`.

There are two ways to get this information.  We can either compare *V<sub>i</sub>* to *V<sub>k</sub>*, or compare *V<sub>j</sub>* to *V<sub>k</sub>*.  Both of these will get us the answers we need (although the precise details for *using* the answers will differ somewhat in some cases).  If we choose—as Git does—to compare *V<sub>i</sub>* to *V<sub>k</sub>*, that gives us two diffs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git's diff also has a "find copies" option, but it's not used in merge and cherry-pick, and I've never found it useful myself.  I think it's a bit deficient internally, i.e., this is an area that—at least someday—needs more work.

---

#### Regular merging

Now we make one more observation:  In a normal true Git merge, we have a setup like this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

where each uppercase letter represents a commit.  Branch names `br1` and `br2` select commits `J` and `L` respectively, and the history working backwards from these two branch-tip commits comes together—joins up—at commit `H`, which is on *both* branches.

To perform `git merge br2`, Git finds *all three of these commits*.  It then runs two `git diff`s: one compares `H` vs `J`, to see what *we* changed in branch `br1`, and the second compares `H` vs `L`, to see what *they* changed in branch `br2`.  Git then *combines the changes* and, if this combining is successful, makes a new merge commit `M`, starting with the files in `H`, that:

- preserves our changes, but also
- adds their changes

and is therefore the correct merge result.  Commit `M` looks like this in the *graph:*

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

but it's the *snapshot* in `M` that matters more to us at the moment: the *snapshot* in `M` *keeps our changes*, i.e., has everything we did in `br1`, and *adds their changes*, i.e., acquires whatever feature or bug-fixes occurred in commits `K` and `L`.

#### Cherry-picking

Our situation is a bit different.  We have:

```
...--P--C--...   <-- somebranch
```

We also have:

```
...--K--L   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
```

where the `...` part might join up with `somebranch` *before* the `P-C` parent/child commit pair, or might join up *after* the `P-C` commit pair, or whatever.  That is, both of these are valid, though the former tends to be more common:

```
...--P--C--...   <-- somebranch
   \
    ...--K--L   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
```

and:

```
...--P--C--...   <-- somebranch
             \
              ...--K--L   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
```

(In the second example, any *changes* made in `P`-vs-`C` are normally *already in* both `K` and `L`, which is why it's less common.  However, it's possible that someone *reverted* commit `C` in one of the `...` sections, on purpose or even by mistake.  For whatever reason, we now want those changes again.)

Running `git cherry-pick` doesn't *just* compare `P`-vs-`C`.  It does indeed do that—this produces the diff / patch we want—but it then goes on to compare `P` vs `L`.  Commit `P` is thus the *merge base* in a `git merge` style comparison.

The diff from `P` to `L` means, in effect, *keep all our differences*.  As with the `H`-vs-`K` example in a true merge, we'll *keep all our changes* in the final commit.  So a new "merge" commit `M` will have our changes.  But Git will *add to this* the changes in `P`-vs-`C`, so we'll pick up the patch changes as well.

The diff from `P` to `L` provides the necessary information about which *file* function `f()` has moved to, if it has moved.  The diff from `P` to `L` provides the necessary information about any *offset* needed for patching function `f()` as well.  So by using the merge machinery, Git gains the ability to apply the patch to the correct line(s) of the correct file(s).

When Git makes the final "merge" commit `M`, though, instead of linking it to *both* input children, Git has it link back *only* to commit `L`:

```
...--P--C--...   <-- somebranch
   \
    ...--K--L--M   <-- ourbranch (HEAD)
```

That is, commit `M` is an ordinary single-parent (non-merge) commit this time.  The *changes* in `L`-vs-`M` are the same as the *changes* in `P`-vs-`C`, except for any change in line offsets and file names that might be required.

Now, there are some caveats here.  In particular, `git diff` doesn't identify *multiple* derived files from some merge base.  If there are changes in `P`-vs-`C` that apply to `file1.ext`, but these changes need to be *split into two files* `file2.ext` and `file3.ext` when patching commit `L`, Git won't notice this.  It's just a little too dumb.  Also, `git diff` finds matching *lines:* it does not understand programming, and if there are spurious matches, such as lots of close braces or parentheses or whatever, that can throw off Git's diff so that it finds the *wrong* matching lines.

Note that Git's *storage system* is just fine here.  It's the *diff* that's not smart enough.  Make `git diff` smarter, and these kinds of operations—merge and cherry-picks—become smarter too.<sup>2</sup>  For now, though, the diff operations, and hence the merges and cherry-picks, are what they are: someone and/or something should *always* inspect the result, by running automated tests, or looking at the files, or anything else you can think of (or a combination of all of these).

---

<sup>2</sup>They will need to machine-read whatever more-complex instructions come out of the diff pass.  Internally, in diff, this is all in one big C program, with the diff engine acting almost like a library, but the principle is the same either way.  There's a hard problem here—adapting to new diff output—and whether the format of this new diff is textual, as in separate programs that produce the diff and then apply it, or binary, as in internal library-like functions that produce change records, all you're doing here is "moving the *hard* around", as a colleague used to say.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. From last paragraph of your explanation - what are the *`commit^1`*  & *`commit`* in my test1 and test2?

Comment: Git has a rich syntax for working with the commit graph.  You can name a commit by its raw SHA-1 (`c18b86734113...` etc), but you can also name it by tracking a path through the commit graph.  Each commit records its parent commit(s), and the `^` syntax selects a particular parent.  You'll see more on commit graphs in chapter 3, e.g., http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging, and on revision selectors in Chapter 7: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: Torek, I've formulated my question in a wrong way, I'm aware about SHA-1, ^ and ~. Let's return to my three commits A,B and C. In last sentence you talked about diff between commit and its parent, which is applied by c-p. So, my question is: in test1 - these commits are 9d5dd4d (A)  and c90c5c8 (C), right? So their diff is "A\n" vs "C\n" and that's the point I don't understand. Why this cherry-pick fails while test2 with diff of "A\n" vs "B\n" succeeds?

Comment: Ah.  No, when you ask to cherry-pick `c90c5c8` git finds its parent, which is `28ad28f`.  Try it: `git rev-parse c90c5c8^`, and `git diff c90c5c8^ c90c5c8`.  Once a commit exists, it can never change.  `git reset` does not change any existing commits, it merely changes which commit the current branch name resolves-to (again, use `git rev-parse` to demonstrate this: `git rev-parse master` will show its current raw SHA-1).

Comment: Yes, each snapshot 'knows' who is its parent(s). But why cherry-pick does use this information? Technically it just should compare content of file in commit 'A' vs content of 'C', *without* relation to 'B'. We can also see that in the last lines of test1 block: there is no 'B' content in the conflict..

Comment: Cherry-pick compares a commit to its parent because that's how it's defined.  You give git one or more commit IDs, and git finds each named commit's parent (or the `-m`'th parent if a merge) and does a diff and then attempts to apply that diff.  In this case the diff is "change B to C" and there is no B so you get the patch-application error you observed.  (If you want something else done, then you don't want the cherry-pick command.  For instance, if you just want a particular snapshot's version of some file, use `git checkout <revspec> -- <path>`, or `git show <revspec>:<path>`.)

Comment: *Cherry-pick compares a commit to its parent because that's how it's defined.* That's my problem :) The commit itself is a 'snapshot' but cherry-pick uses 'patches'. Thank you, torek.

Comment: @torek: "You are also correct, though: git cherry-pick applies a patch" goes against what you've said in other answers, e.g. "[While git cherry-pick is often described as "apply a patch", that's not really what it does. That is a shorthand for what it really does. It really performs a three-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59234599/8910547)". and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932137/8910547. Maybe clarify?

Comment: @Inigo: I'll give it a try...