# Unexpected behaviour Git applying patch (cherry-pick): not only the commit was taken

Tags: git

I always been using cherry-pick so I supposed to be pretty confident in that statement:

- **cherry-pick** take ONLY changes made in the cherry picked commit. stop.

but it happened that on an usual merge, it took also unwanted changes from another commit.

I simplify my use case:

- I'm cherry-picking the `tocherry` commit on top of master, avoiding `tonotcherry` changes

```sh
user@laptop:(master)test$ git log --graph  --oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --all
* 6fee67e (HEAD -> master) unused
| * 7c9de69 (feature) tocherry
| * fffe063 tonotcherry
|/
* 970888c init
user@laptop:(master)test$ git show fffe063
commit fffe063be9cd11c0fb8406a8e8806bfd2ea71d74

    tonotcherry

diff --git a/Class.cs b/Class.cs
index 8fa6580..ae5f69e 100644
--- a/Class.cs
+++ b/Class.cs
@@ -5,12 +5,14 @@ namespace ciao
        public class Test
        {
                private string attribute1;
+               private string attribute2;

                public Test Test(
-                               string _attribute1
-               )
+                               string _attribute1,
+                               string _attribute2)
                {
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
+                       this.attribute2 = _attribute2;
                }
        }
 }
user@laptop:(master)test$ git log --graph  --oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --all
* 6fee67e (HEAD -> master) unused
| * 7c9de69 (feature) tocherry
| * fffe063 tonotcherry
|/
* 970888c init
user@laptop:(master)test$ git show fffe063
commit fffe063be9cd11c0fb8406a8e8806bfd2ea71d74

    tonotcherry

diff --git a/Class.cs b/Class.cs
index 8fa6580..ae5f69e 100644
--- a/Class.cs
+++ b/Class.cs
@@ -5,12 +5,14 @@ namespace ciao
        public class Test
        {
                private string attribute1;
+               private string attribute2;

                public Test Test(
-                               string _attribute1
-               )
+                               string _attribute1,
+                               string _attribute2)
                {
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
+                       this.attribute2 = _attribute2;
                }
        }
 }
user@laptop:(master)test$ git show 7c9de69
commit 7c9de69d8461642867b7c5b1395b11abbf918b96 (feature)

    tocherry

diff --git a/Class.cs b/Class.cs
index ae5f69e..f5f88ff 100644
--- a/Class.cs
+++ b/Class.cs
@@ -6,13 +6,19 @@ namespace ciao
        {
                private string attribute1;
                private string attribute2;
+               private string attribute3;
+               private string attribute4;

                public Test Test(
                                string _attribute1,
-                               string _attribute2)
+                               string _attribute2,
+                               string _attribute3,
+                               string _attribute4)
                {
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
                        this.attribute2 = _attribute2;
+                       this.attribute3 = _attribute3;
+                       this.attribute4 = _attribute4;
                }
        }
 }
user@laptop:(master)test$ git show 6fee67e
commit 6fee67e42b675de94b385bca461336326a36c46f (HEAD -> master)

    unused

diff --git a/Class.cs b/Class.cs
index 8fa6580..c189487 100644
--- a/Class.cs
+++ b/Class.cs
@@ -12,5 +12,9 @@ namespace ciao
                {
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
                }
+
+               public string someFunction() {
+                       return "";
+               }
        }
 }
 user@laptop:(master)test$ git cherry-pick -x 7c9de69d8461642867b7c5b1395b11abbf918b96
error: could not apply 7c9de69... tocherry
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
user@laptop:(master)test$ cat Class.cs
using System;

namespace ciao
{
    public class Test
    {
        private string attribute1;
<<<<<<< HEAD

        public Test Test(
                string _attribute1
        )
        {
            this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
        }

        public string someFunction() {
            return "";
=======
        private string attribute2;
        private string attribute3;
        private string attribute4;

        public Test Test(
                string _attribute1,
                string _attribute2,
                string _attribute3,
                string _attribute4)
        {
            this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
            this.attribute2 = _attribute2;
            this.attribute3 = _attribute3;
            this.attribute4 = _attribute4;
>>>>>>> 7c9de69... tocherry
        }
    }
}
```

Input parameters in constructor apart, which is ambiguous by comma and parenthesis, I supposed to not see `attribute2` during the cherry-pick commit, because that is only part of `fffe063`.

Is this related in how git store differences and apply merges? how can I predict that? Is there any way to avoid that behaviour?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this related in how git store differences

Git doesn't *store* differences (instead, it *computes* them every time you run `git diff` or `git show` or `git log -p`), but that is not important here:

> and apply merges?

This is the important part.

While `git cherry-pick` is often described as "apply a patch", that's not really what it does.  That is a shorthand for what it really does.  It really performs a three-way merge.

*If* the merge goes well, Git will then commit the result automatically.  This final commit is an ordinary commit, not a merge commit.  If the merge *does not* go well, however, you get to see the intermediate merge.

> how can I predict that?

It *is* possible to predict, but it's much easier to just perform the cherry-pick operation.  If you'd like to do your own predicting, we will see how in a moment.

> Is there any way to avoid that behaviour?

Not really.  You should just fix the conflicts and continue the rebase operation to finish it.

You may want to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`: I find these conflicts much more readable.  See below.

#### The three-way merge

The heart of the problem is that cherry-pick needs to apply changes that may not actually apply.  To make this work better—but not 100%—Git uses the three-way merge code.  The *merge base* of this merge is the parent of the commit being cherry-picked.  The *current commit*, or `HEAD`, is the commit you have checked out—in this case, `6fee67e` which is the tip of `master`.  The commit you are cherry picking is the third commit in this three-way merge.

In a more typical merge, we have a situation that looks like this:

```
          o--o--L   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--o--R   <-- their-branch
```

The three interesting commits, which are the inputs to the merge operation, are the *merge base* commit `B` (and its snapshot), the current commit `L` (for Left or Local) at the tip of your own branch, and commit `R` (for Right or Remote or otheR) at the tip of their branch.

This kind of merge will:

- compare `B` vs `L` to see what *you* changed; and
- compare `B` vs `R` to see what *they* changed.

Git then extracts all the files from `B`, *combines* your work from `B`-vs-`L` with their work from `B`-vs-`R`, and applies the *combined* changes to the files from `B`.

If all goes well, Git makes a new merge commit, which becomes the tip of your branch:

```
          o--o--L
         /       \
...--o--B         M   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         \       /
          o--o--R   <-- their-branch
```

New commit `M` has parents `L` and `R` (both) and the snapshot that was made by applying the combined changes from both branch tips to the files as seen in commit `B`.  This way you get both sets of changes applied.

For a cherry-pick, however, our picture looks more like this:

```
          o--o--L   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--B--R--o--...--o   <-- their-branch
```

(in your particular case, their branch name points directly to commit `R`).  While commit `*` is the actual merge base of your branch and their branch, it is *not* the commit that `git cherry-pick` uses as the merge base.

Instead, Git uses the parent of `R`—commit `B` in this diagram—as the merge base.  So once again, it compares `B`-vs-`L` to see what *you* changed, and `B`-vs-`R` to see what *they* changed.  If these changes conflict—as they do in your case—the merge stops in the middle.

If all had gone well—which it didn't in your case—Git would have applied the *combined* changes to the snapshot in `B` as usual.  So that would keep the difference between `B` and `L`, while adding the difference between `B` and `R`.  In other words, it would apply the patches required to go from commit `B` to commit `R`.

#### Predicting whether there will be conflicts

To do this predicting, you can run your own comparisons of `B`-vs-`L` and `B`-vs-`R`.  First, get the parent hash ID of the commit you plan to cherry-pick.  In this case it's `fffe063`.  You might cut and paste this as needed, or just store it in a variable:

```
$ B=fffe063
```

Then, run `git diff --find-renames` on commit `B` and commit `L`.  You can name commit `L` easily using the name `HEAD`:

```
$ git diff --find-renames $B HEAD
```

Whatever shows up here, make note of each changed source line(s) in the original file(s).

Then, run `git diff --find-renames` on commit `B` and commit `R`:

```
$ git diff --find-renames $B 7c9de69
```

Whatever shows up here, make note of each changed source line(s) in the original file(s).

If the two sets-of-changes touch the *same* lines of the *same* files, there will be a conflict.  If the two sets of changes always touch *different files*, or *different, sufficiently-far-away*<sup>1</sup> lines, there will be no conflicts: Git will be able to combine the changes.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Sufficiently far away" basically means that the changes neither overlap, nor touch head-to-tail.  If both changes insert at the front or end of the file, they will overlap.  The English word for these head/tail or both-at-same-end-of-file "touching" cases is *abut*; see, e.g., https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abut.

---

#### How to read the conflict

The lines between `<<<<<<< HEAD` and `=======` come from the difference between commit `B` and your current (`HEAD`) commit `L`.  You probably want to keep these changes.

The lines between `=======` and `>>>>>>> ...` come from the difference between commit `B` and their commit `R`—in this case, the one you are cherry-picking.  You probably want to keep *these* changes too!

It is up to you to combine these two sets of changes sensibly.  It is often very helpful to see what was in the merge-base version of this file—i.e., what was in the file that comes just before commit `R`, in your case.  But Git does not show you these lines by default.  The default is to use `merge` for `merge.conflictStyle`.

If you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`, Git adds a *third* set of lines, with `|||||||` as the marker.  This third set of lines are the original lines in commit `B`.  You can therefore compare them by eye to those from commits `L` and `R` in the `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>` sections.

#### You may use a merge tool instead

If you don't like these methods, `git mergetool` is available.  I do not use these various merge tools myself and can only give very general guidance.  Search for existing StackOverflow postings on using various merge tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict here because your picked commit `7c9de69` has a different start point to your master branch (on commit `6fee67e`). This is because commit `fffe063` modified that same piece of code, so git is asking you to resolve this since it can't decide how this should be done...

```
user@laptop:(master)test$ git show 7c9de69
commit 7c9de69d8461642867b7c5b1395b11abbf918b96 (feature)

    tocherry

diff --git a/Class.cs b/Class.cs
index ae5f69e..f5f88ff 100644
--- a/Class.cs
+++ b/Class.cs
@@ -6,13 +6,19 @@ namespace ciao
        {
                private string attribute1;
                private string attribute2;
+               private string attribute3;
+               private string attribute4;

                public Test Test(
                                string _attribute1,
-                               string _attribute2)   <----- NOT POSSIBLE
+                               string _attribute2,
+                               string _attribute3,
+                               string _attribute4)
                {
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
                        this.attribute2 = _attribute2;
+                       this.attribute3 = _attribute3;
+                       this.attribute4 = _attribute4;
                }
        }
 }
```

Comment: I see, but I expected that cherry picking does not take in account either `fffe063` either the starting point: I though the merge was on the actual file and the "diff" (as + or -) of `7c9de69 `.

I also see that I misunderstood  the way that git is applying the patches. Do you know any resource which is explaining that process?

Comment: @RiccardoBucchi `git show 7c9de69` commit says it needs to remove this line: `string _attribute2)` which does not exist because `fffe063` has not happened, so git cannot resolve this. That is shown in the git show command you displayed in your question. It is simply a merge conflict, nothing more : )

Comment: updated my post to highlight the part of the commit that is not possible

Comment: the line u highlighted I exptected to be on conflict, I was talking 

```
                        this.attribute1 = _attribute1;
                        this.attribute2 = _attribute2; <--- THAT LINE IS TAKEN BY MERGE
+                       this.attribute3 = _attribute3;
+                       this.attribute4 = _attribute4;
```

which still however as I can see cannot be resolved by auto merge

Comment: it is all the same section of code, so it is coming under the same conflict